# Git in practice

Tags: git, github

I would like help understanding how professional developers typically use Git. Now I am aware of Git and its usages, what I need to understand from a best practice perspective is at what stage does one consider it relevant to commit changes.

Perhaps this could be subjective but could someone with experience enlighten me.
For example:
If I was modifying an existing function, I would perhaps commit after the modification. Or if I was writing new code, I would commit after completing say a function.

Comment: It is really up to your own preference.  Some developers commit often out of paranoia.  But then some will squash down commits if they look ugly.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to learn Git is to create a really simple project with a few text files in it and then experiment like crazy. You can play around with all the Git commands and sync with GitHub repos to your heart’s content without worrying about doing any coding.

**Few Basic Functionalities:**

***Check the status with ‘git status’***
Whenever you want to see what the Git status of your project is enter git status. Initially, you will see that there is nothing to report

***Tracking files***
Tracking means that Git knows about them. If you add a new file, Git will not know about it and needs to be explicitly told.

Add a new file (test.txt) and add a few random characters to it.
Open any other existing file (I chose humans.txt) and make a small, harmless change to it.
Run git status again and you should see

To tell GitHub to track the file, you can do one of the following

git add . which tells Git to track all files in the project that are not yet tracked. This is the quickest and simplest way to track any new files.
git add FILENAME explicitly tracks a single file

***Committing your changes***
Committing means that you want to add your staged, files into the repository. There are two ways to do this…

git commit -m 'commit message' will take all staged files and commit them to the repo.
git commit -a -m 'commit message' will do the same but the -a switch tells Git to automatically stage any tracked files before committing them. This means that you don’t have to use git add at all (unless you want to add new, untracked files).

***Reverting***
One of the nice things you can do is to revert your code back to an earlier commit. git revert is the command for rolling back like this. There are a number of ways to use this, simple uses are

git revert 'commit id' reverts back to the SHA (uid) you can see when you type git log
git revert HEAD will revert back to the last commit, throwing away any uncommitted changes
git revert HEAD~n for example HEAD~3 will revert to the 4rd last commit.
git revert HEAD^^^ (count of ^ is like ~n) will also revert back to the 4th last commit

***Pushing to a remote repository***
If you want to send your committed changes to a remote repository, you will use the git push command. First, however, you need to make sure that you have a remote set up.